# How to return go (array/slice/ist) to a C function

Tags: go, cgo

I have C code in which I am calling golang functions. I am able to do it for primitives data types (int/float etc.) but I want to return some other data structure like array/list/slice.
I could not find any solution on internet.

Looking for help.

Want to return a array/slice/list of string data type.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you provide additional information, i.e. example code you are currently working on.

As stated from the [`Cgo` documentation page](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go):

> Go array types are not supported; use a C pointer

To do so

#### `hello.go`

```golang
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import "unsafe"

// StringSlice is a wrapper arround GoStringSlice to make it usable in C.
//export StringSlice
func StringSlice() **C.char {
    x := GoStringSlice()
    ret := C.malloc(C.size_t(len(x)) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))

    // convert to usable format so we are able to fill it with data
    pRet := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.char)(ret)

    for i, item := range x {
        pRet[i] = C.CString(item)
    }

    return (**C.char)(ret)

}

func GoStringSlice() []string {
    return []string{
        "Hello",
        "World",
    }
}

func main() {}
```

#### `hello.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");

    char **slice = StringSlice();
    int numItems = sizeof(slice) / sizeof(char *);

    printf("Number of items: %d\n", numItems+1);

    printf("String #0: %s\n", *slice);
    slice++;
    printf("String #1: %s\n", *slice);

    return 0;
}
```

You have to execute `go build -buildmode=c-archive hello.go` which will generate a `hello.h` and `hello.a`.
The `hello.a` has to be compiled with your C code: `gcc -pthread hello.c hello.a -o hello`.

Comment: not need free memory? and what does this line mean：pRet := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.char)(ret)